# Is it possible to convert a String array with two comma separated numbers into a variable of type Point

Tags: vb.net, type-conversion

I have a formatted text string containing two comma separated numbers, e.g.:

```
sText as String = "10, 20"
```

I would like to convert this string into a Point type.

```
oPoint = ?
```

My approach was to first split the string into an array of numbers using

```
sText.Split(","c)
```

This should yield a string array with 2 fields containing "10" and "20".

How would I continue to assign it to the Point type?

```
oPoint = sText.Split(","c).Select(Function(n) Integer.Parse(n))
```

doesn't work.

Comment: Consider the answer given below by MatSnow, I just want to explain why it won't work for anyone who comes across this in future. `.Select(Function(n) Integer.Parse(n))` will return an `IEnumerable(Of Integer)` so you were fighting a losing battle. You would have had to work with the individual elements of the returned array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
Dim sText As String = "10, 20"
Dim splittedText As String() = sText.Split(","c)
Dim oPoint As New Point(Integer.Parse(splittedText(0)), Integer.Parse(splittedText(1)))
```